# How to extract the text from the sibling text nodes of the strong tag using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

There are 52 page objects as follows, all of which has Strong tag containing a String called "Gideon".
How possibly can I get all of them by findElements method?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *"quotes"* are within a *text nodes*. So to retrieve the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the  `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> parentElements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Gideon']//..")));
  for (WebElement parentElement:parentElements)
      System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", parentElement).toString());
  ```
- `xpath` with *preceding*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> parentElements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Gideon']//preceding::p[1]")));
  for (WebElement parentElement:parentElements)
      System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", parentElement).toString());
  ```